# JTextPane + JScrollPane + word wrap?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane, word-wrap

Based on existing solutions, I haven't found a way to make a JTextPane (or JEditorPane) have either word-wrap or forced line-wrap inside a JScrollPane. JTextArea is not a solution as I need HTML to display in the particular input.

```
output = new JTextPane();
scrollPane.setViewportView(output);
contentPane.add(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);
output.setEditorKit(new WrapEditorKit());
output.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
output.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12));
output.setEditable(false);
output.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
output.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
```

The WrapEditorKit is the one available [here](http://java-sl.com/wrap.html). I have also tried ScrollablePanel, but every time the JTextPane's text is not wrapped at all. How would one go around to implement a JTextPane inside a JScrollPane with only **vertical** scrolling (and horizontal word or forced line wrap)?

Comment: Does it work with a normal JPanel?

Comment: @Tabaqui: what do you mean "does it work with a normal JPanel"? The original poster's question has nothing to do with JPanel, normal or otherwise.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i was trying to figure out if playing with getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() (Overriding it) could help, but i don't have my JDK to test here :/

Comment: I am not a JTextPane expert, but if you're showing HTML, could using CSS style sheets help you wrap text? Again, I have no idea if this is possible or even if JTextPane's HTML editor kit supports this.

Comment: Wrapping of text works fine for me using the standard editor kit with a JTextPane using JDK7 on Windows 7. Post a complete example and include simple HTML with your example that demonstrates the problem. That is post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). A few lines of code don't help us solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is apparently caused by the `<pre>` tags rather than any other setting. Without the `<pre>` tags, the text seems to wrap properly. I originally added them to prevent an another issue with newlines, but I'll try to fix it using some other method then. This could've never have happened with some more advanced HTML skills.

Comment: Again, this is the reason you post your `SSCCE`. We can't guess what your code or HTML looks like to cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some 6 years later I had the same problem. Mine was not caused by <pre> tags - didn't have them in the text.

**Solution:**
Subclass `JEditorPane` or (`JTextPane` which is a subclass of `JEditorPane`) and override [`boolean javax.swing.Scrollable#getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html#getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()).
Returning true from this method forces a `Scrollable` (such as a `JTextPane`) to wrap its contents instead of activating horizontal scroll if the enclosing `JScrollPane`.

According to the docs should work with all them `Scrollable`s:
*DefaultTreeCellEditor.DefaultTextField, JEditorPane, JFormattedTextField, JLayer, JList, JPasswordField, JTable, JTextArea, JTextComponent, JTextField, JTextPane, JTree*.